# Vue ()=> import('some/component.vue') syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

My question is about this syntax:

```
{
  component: ()=> import('./SomeComp.vue')
}
```

I understand what arrow function is, but how does this work? Is this legal ES syntax or something Vue does that is standardized with babel?

Comment: It's [dynamic `import`](http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html), a not-yet legal ES syntax.

Comment: @Bergi that's what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`import('./SomeComp.vue')` is a dynamic import. It extends on top of ES2015 module specification and currently in [stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import). As specified, `import()` returns a promise which is resolved when the specified module is loaded.

Currently, you will need a bundler like Webpack or Rollup. They emulate this behavior.

In the context of Vue.js, a component can be asynchronous means a component will be a function that returns a promise. When the promise is resolved, the `default` export value will be used as `Component` definition.

Comment: "*It is part of ES2015 module specification*" - no, it's not. ES2015 specifies static imports only. It's currently a stage 3 proposal.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for pointing out. It is indeed a separate proposal.